# Почему не работает toggle на JQuery 1.11?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Почему не работает toggle на JQuery 1.11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В версии JQuery 1.8 toggle объявлен устаревшим, в версии 1.9 удален.
Необходимо использовать click.